# Ubuntu 22.04 has internet and wifi but dns probe finished gives bad config error

Tags: server, internet, dns, dnsmasq, resolv.conf

I get this error every time I turn on the computer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2kQH.png)

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

every time i run this command it changes the etc/resolv.conf file

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

When I put the computer to sleep, it also changes the etc/resolv.conf file to `nameserver 127.0.0.1`.

To solve the problem, I run the commands every time I turn on the computer.

```
sudo unlink /etc/resolv.conf

echo nameserver 8.8.8.8 | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

but this way I can access the internet with google chrome and a few apps

later on

`valet update` I am running the command

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RgNj5.jpg)

After these processes are completed

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
```

I run the command and internet is opened in all applications.

I want to use the computer normally I do not want to do these operations every time

Answer (score -1):

Ive got same problem. Just restart Network manager and changed nameserver through nano.
It works after reboot/shutdown